# SSL handshake shows cipher 0000

Tags: ssl

My SSL handshake (using the openssl s_client -connect host:port) show this output:

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1631731107
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

It is showing return code 0 (ok), start time etc. Does this mean a SSL session is established here? Why does it not show other things like cipher, session-id etc which I normally see with other SSL sessions?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

From `https://www.virtuesecurity.com/kb/null-ciphers-supported/`:

```
Cipher Name (IANA)      Cipher Name (OpenSSL)   Value
TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL N/A                     0x00,0x00
```

See also `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_cipher`.

Just don't use it,there's no encryption.

Comment: I very much doubt this answer. Connecting with this cipher would require the client to actually offer the cipher to the server and to server to actually support it.. No sane client would offer it and no sane server accept such offer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Also, I'm pretty certain out-of-the-box OpenSSL versions that support TLS1.2 don't support `NULL` ciphers anyway; it has to be explicitly enabled when compiling.  And someone who has to ask any question about what OpenSSL's output means likely wouldn't have the ability to compile OpenSSL like that - and once they did, they'd have enough knowledge of OpenSSL to not have to ask here.

Answer (score 3):

This output means that the handshake was not successful at all. There is usually an error somewhere in the output preceding this, like here:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:80
CONNECTED(00000003)
140501726137216:error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number:ssl_pkt.c:386:
....
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    ...
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

In this example a TLS connection was attempted to a server which does not speak TLS at all but instead speaks only plain HTTP (since I've connected to the plain HTTP port). There is a clear error showing some kind of TLS problem, which in this case is caused by trying to interpret a plain HTTP response as TLS.